# An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. - Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, database, xna, linq-to-entities

been looking around and i just cant seem to figure out what is wrong.

Currently i'm trying to update my database with a new highscore when ever the player dies. But it keeps throwing that exception at me, no matter what i choose to try and save.

Code:

```
 HighScore hs = new HighScore();
            var id = from i in db.HighScores
                     orderby i.ID descending
                     select i;
            int newId = 0;

            if (id.Count() == 0)
            {
                newId = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                newId = id.First().ID + 1;
            }
        hs.ID = 6; //I just hardcoded in 6 to make sure i wasent because of the newId      //thing, and i have checked if theres already something on the sixths spot as well.
            hs.UserHighscore = 100;
            hs.HighscoreUsername = "test";
            hs.GameID = 1;
            db.HighScores.AddObject(hs);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

I've checked, again and again, and i just cant seem to figure out what the problem is.

Any help would be appriciated.

The exception:

```
System.Data.UpdateException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
       at MatematikSpilMenu.SaveBunniesSceen.SaveHighscore() in MatematikSpilMenu\SaveBunniesSceen.cs:line 173
       at MatematikSpilMenu.SaveBunniesSceen.Update(GameTime gameTime, Boolean otherScreenIsActive, Boolean coveredByOtherScreens) in C:\Users\Etarnalazure-Alien\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MatematikSpilMenu\MatematikSpilMenu\MatematikSpilMenu\SaveBunniesSceen.cs:line 110
       at MatematikSpilMenu.ScreenManager.Update(GameTime gameTime) in MatematikSpilMenu\ScreenManager.cs:line 101
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Update(GameTime gameTime)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.RunOneFrame()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.ApplicationIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(Int32 grfidlef)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.Run()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
       at MatematikSpilMenu.Program.Main() in MatematikSpilMenu\Game1.cs:line 120
  InnerException: System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException
       Message=An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
       Source=System.Data.Entity
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(UpdateTranslator translator, Dictionary`2 identifierValues)
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
       InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
            Message=Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by SQL Server Compact.
            Source=System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlGen.DmlSqlGenerator.GenerateReturningSql(StringBuilder commandText, DbModificationCommandTree tree, ExpressionTranslator translator, DbExpression returning)
                 at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlGen.DmlSqlGenerator.GenerateInsertSql(DbInsertCommandTree tree, List`1& parameters, Boolean isLocalProvider)
                 at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlGen.SqlGenerator.GenerateSql(DbCommandTree tree, List`1& parameters, CommandType& commandType, Boolean isLocalProvider)
                 at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
                 at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
                 at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree)
                 at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree commandTree)
                 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
            InnerException:
```

Comment: Would be easier if we could have the message of the actual inner exception... ? What is GameID ? a foreign key ? is ther a game with ID 1 ?

Comment: GameID is the ID i use to pull out the appropriate highscore for the appropriate game. GameID = 1 is used to tell the game where which Highscore should get pulled out.

Comment: But I'll get a hold of the Inner exception

Comment: Whether you have checked that HIghScore table is null or not?

Comment: Kamal, sorry but i didnt understand what you where trying to say =/ Could you rephrase it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the root of the problems resides on the SQL server you use:

> Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by
>   SQL Server Compact.

Are you trying to use an auto increment ID on  SQL server Compact version? I'm not remember well, but maybe that is not possible with that SQL version. I suggest you to check that first.

Comment: Thing is, Its worked before on a form. Unless theres a difference between the two?

Comment: I do not understand you exactly. You mean the same code was run once before? If it is, than you have to check through what did you change since that. From the exception message it seems that the problem is with the database. Did you chang the database behind it?

Comment: Just tried removing Auto Increment on the ID off, still gave me the same error.

Comment: Isn't it possible that your 'db.HighScores' object tries to handle it as identity still?

Comment: I dont think so, because i had to delete it and reinsert it since it kept giving me errors, would screenshots help?

Comment: Not sure, but let's give it a try!

Comment: There is no additional information on it unfortunately. The exception remained totally the same after identity removal? Wasn't any change in it? In the inner exception I mean.

Comment: Ah, i neglected to check. Give me a minute

Comment: Still the same message:
Message=Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by SQL Server Compact.

Comment: What's your table definition exactly. Can you show the table definition SQL?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12299/discussion-between-etarnalazure-and-csaba-benko)

Comment: Just one more idea, if you would like to check: Isn't that possible, that the table innsert causes some other tables to update too? 
On the Entity model I did not see any connections, but maybe there are in the database server level? If you are not tired of my ideas, then try to check this one.

Comment: I'll give it a try, i was actually just thinking something like "What if theres a foreign key somewhere using it"

Comment: doesent seem like its the case =/

Comment: Fixed it.. Created a new table and tried it with that.. Worked.. Except it added the score 140 times.

Comment: :) 

So the database was the guilty in it, as we thought.

I'm glad, the at last you have a working solution now. :)

Answer (score 5):

Well from my experience that is usually triggered by a db error, in my case it was a trigger associated with the table that was failing and throwing the root exception. In your case however it seems that you are mistakenly trying to define the id manually when using an auto-numbered (identity) field.

Comment: Thank you for making me think of triggers.  I was at the end of my rope.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, it seems that its the database that can bug if in use too many places (This is just me guessing). Either way, creating a new table and then adding stuff to there seemed to fix it (Did not use Identity.)

Answer (score 1):

In my case after switching on the table database the primary key to an auto_ink column the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

Server-generated keys are not performing well so go and check the database may be ur database primery key is auto generated key so go and try to insert data manually